# Java HTTPS Server using Keytool

Tags: java, ssl, https, keytool

I'm using the following to initialize an HTTPS driven server for a secure website.  The keystore command is as follows:

keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias mykey -keystore keystore.jks -keypass password -storepass password -validity 365 -keysize 2048

After running the code I get a bad_certificate error message when I attempt to load my website and a yellow screen appears.  What am I doing wrong?

```
        String path = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SSLTest5";
        String file = path + "\\" + "keystore.jks";
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(file),"password".toCharArray());
         
        // Create key manager
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "password".toCharArray());
        KeyManager[] km = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
         
        // Create trust manager
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
        TrustManager[] tm = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
         
        // Initialize SSLContext
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(km,  tm, null);
        
        SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketFactory = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
        SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(443);
        
        
        System.out.println("Waiting for client...");

        SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();

        HandleAccept(sslSocket);
```

Comment: The cert generated by `keytool -genkey[pair]` is **self-signed**, not signed by a trusted CA, and thus not trusted by most clients. Many clients can be configured to trust such a such by treating it as a pseudo-CA cert and 'importing' or 'installing' it, but the details vary for each client, and you didn't say what client(s) you use, and whether it is (or they are) programmed by you, somebody else, or not at all.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, the name you answer(ed) to the `keytool` prompt for "first and last name" must actually be the server name (usually a Fully Qualified Domain Name FQDN) _as used in the URLs that access it_, which is not obvious to many people. This is really the 'CommonName' attribute in the certificate, which is used unless you specify a SAN = Subject Alternative Name extension, which you didn't, although using SAN is now the preferred method.